# Can a clone be of the same age as the original

Tags: science-based, biology, anatomy, cloning, neuroscience

If I clone a 50 year old what are the ways I can get a 50 year old clone ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually people go for DNA splicing then starts the life cycle from the begining not continue the cell division of a 50yo, actually that will be regeneration lol

Comment: *"If I clone a 50 year old what are the ways I can get a 50 year old clone?" Obviously, all you have to do in order to get a fifty year old clone is to wait fifty years.

Comment: If you'd had the [science-fiction] tag instead of the [science-based] one, the answer could be easy - but since we don't have a lot of practice with humans (or notable success growing healthy higher-animal) clones, we can only tell you about what is possible now, i.e. not much.

Comment: With the [tag:science-based] tag, the only way humanity knows of to get a 50-year-old clone is to wait 50 years. Cloning like you see in the movies or read about in fiction doesn't exist. @Escapeddentalpatient is right, if we shift to [tag:science-fiction] then we can suggest things like Star Trek teleporters, which operate by duplicating, then destroying, the original (kinda). This was also the central conceit of the movie *[The Prestige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige_(film)),* but the original wasn't destroyed (well... kinda).

Comment: You can't, in the real world it's just not possible, lots of films and novels either throw magic sci fi handwavium at it to explain it or just ignore reality and do it anyway of course so there's no reason you can't as well, just don't fool yourself that it's a real thing .. the only semi-plausible workaround is grow cells on lattices mode3lled on adult size organs and stitch them together, the cells might be cloned but it's not one, more an organic construct, the brain made that way will come with as little or even less preloaded 'software' than a new born baby, so it seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 2):

## Real life clones were healthy

We have done cloning in the past! A famous example is Dolly the sheep. It might not be the cloning you are looking for however. The DNA was harvested from a 6 year old sheep. To massively simplify what happened next, the DNA was added to the egg cell of another sheep, which was put to grow in even another sheep. The cloning was basically creating an identical twin, 6 years after the first one was born.

The result was a new lamb. Like all twins, they do **not** magically share knowledge and skills. This lamb started from scratch. The sheep did raise a lot of questions, like if it would start aging as if it was already 6 years old. Several other lesser known studies followed. Though the sample size isn't large, their conclusion was that the cloned sheeps this way didn't 'start' ageing as a 6 year old sheep.

Cloning a grown creature to create another grown creature instantly hasn't been done. This would also offer a lot of problems. Unless you have some very (currently) sci-fi technology, you can't mold the brain or nerves to have all the knowledge and skills of the original. In your case  this would mean that if you created a 50 year old clone somehow, the clone wouldn't be able to walk or talk. They would in essence be a 50 year old new born.

So in general there is currently no way to generate a 50 year old clone. If you could, by for example bombarding the DNA with radiation to match normal damages at 50, you would still have a 'newborn' in a 50 year old body. With current technology and understanding it is not possible.

Comment: I've never seen any scientific basis for an "adult clone" myself (outside any sci fi using copious amounts of handwavium or just ignoring the unreality of their "science" of course) .. the only ***semi-plausible*** workaround is probably grow cells on lattices modelled on adult size organs and 'stitch' them together, the cells could be cloned but it won't be one of course, more an organic construct, the brain made that way will come with as little or more likely even less preloaded 'software' than a new born baby, so it seems a bit pointless unless you want a whole body transplant maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Sort of.

[Dolly the Sheep](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC305328/) started off as a lamb but her DNA had the telomeres of the older animal that she was cloned from, which meant she aged prematurely.  We would have had to reconstruct the telomeres of a young sheep to give her a normal lifespan.

Comment: The source you've quoted further states that telomeres aren't the main way to determine age. Also, they see that some cell clusters that had lived about 95% of their life span could produce healthy lambs with longer telomeres than the control group. The sample size is small, but leans to no aging effects from cloning this way.